# glmer: distribution law for number of events / time

Tags: time-series, distributions, model, glmm, gamma-distribution

Sorry if this is a basic question but I can't find an answer that is clear enough, so I prefer to ask.

I want to model a number of events (number of gaze) that depends on the behaviour that one individual did (0 if he hasn't done it yet, 1 if he has. Once the individual has done the behaviour, the value remains 1 until the end of the trial) and the number of individuals that already did this behaviour (ranging from 0, nobody did it, to 4, and that includes the target subject). For this, I created on R a table that shows, for each trial and each individual, how many gaze he has for every combination of whether he did the behaviour and the number of individual that did the behaviour. We have no control over who does the behaviour and when, thus not every individual has the same combination of Behaviour and Number_of_ind, and duration of this combinations are different. For example, ind A can be the first to do the behaviour, so for him the data will be as follow, for one trial:

```
Ind <- c(A,A,A)
Behaviour <- c(0,1,1)   
Number_of_ind <- c(0,1,2)
Duration  <- c(2,3,4) 
Nb_of_gaze <- c(3,1,0)
```

For A, combinations are as follow: when the behaviour is of 0, the number of individuals is of 0, and when the behaviour is of 1, the number of individuals is of 1 and 2. While if B is the 2nd to do the behaviour, the data will be like this for him for this trial:

```
Ind <- c(B,B,B)
Behaviour <- c(0,0,1)   
Number_of_ind <- c(0,1,2)
Duration  <- c(2,3,4) 
Nb_of_gaze <- c(0,0,1)
```

Thus, for B, combinations are as follow: when the behaviour is of 0, the number of individuals is of 0 and 1, and when the behaviour is of 1, the number of individuals is of 2.

The model would be something like

```
glmer(Nb_of_gaze ~ Behaviour + Number_of_ind + random factors, family="...")
```

But, I can't find the correct distribution law, mainly because the duration of each "combination" is different between and within trials (it depends on whether an individual does the behaviour or not, we have no control over this). NB: however, the duration of each trial is fixed, but with our question, we had to "cut" the trial into small "combinations".

First, I wanted to use a Poisson (number of gaze depending on whether the individual did the behaviour and the number of individual that did it) but if I understood right, it requires that all duration are equals, which is not our case.

Second, I wanted to use a binomial, and instead of counting the number of gaze I wrote 0 if no gaze was done and 1 if at least one gaze was done. But here again, this is biased by the fact that duration are very different.

Thus, I thought that I should calculate the number of gaze/second (Nb of gaze / Duration) for each "combination" and use a Gamma distribution. But I can't find whether Gamma is the correct distribution law for this.

Do you have any idea of how to deal with this? Is Gamma ok for a ratio nb of events/duration ?

I hope that this is clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for more information if needed, Thank you very much in advance for your help !